# cyclic traversal over enum

Tags: java, enums

what is the best way of cyclic traversal over an enum.

I have an enum Directions and i want to traverse over it cyclically. currently i have implemented next method in enum which returns next value, i was just wondering is there any better way/inbuilt support for cyclic traversal.

current code

```
enum Direction {
    east, north, west, south;

    Direction next() {

        switch (this) {
        case east:
            return north;

        case north:
            return west;

        case west:
            return south;

        case south:
            return east;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert to int (through `ordinal()`), cycle and convert back to enum (through `values[i]`).

Like this:

```
Direction next() {
    return values()[(ordinal() + 1) % values().length];
}
```

### Generic Solution

A more generic way of cycling through enum values is:

```
class CyclicIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private final T[] values;
    private int current;

    public CyclicIterator(T[] values) {
        this.values = values;
        this.current = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        current = (current + 1) % values.length;
        return values[current];
    }
}
```

Which can be used as follows:

```
CyclicIterator<Direction> iter = new CyclicIterator<>(Direction.values());
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + ": " + iter.next());
}
```

Output:

```
0: north
1: west
2: south
3: east
4: north
5: west
```

### Guava solution

If you depend on Guava, a cyclic iterator (identical to the one above) is already available through [`Iterators.cycle`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.google.guava/guava/30.1.1-jre/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#cycle(java.lang.Iterable))

Answer (score 8):

It would be pretty simple to implement an cyclic `Iterator`:

```
enum Direction implements Iterable<Direction> {
    east, north, west, south;

    @Override
    public Iterator<Direction> iterator() {
        return new DirectionIterator();
    }

    class DirectionIterator implements Iterator<Direction> {

        Direction next = Direction.this;

        @Override
        public Direction next() {
            try {
                return next;
            } finally {
                next = values()[(next.ordinal() + 1) % values().length];
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() { 
            return true; 
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Iterator<Direction> it = Direction.north.iterator();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Outputs:

```
north
west
south
east
north
west
south
east
north
west
```

Comment: With aioobe's idea of putting a `next()` method on the enum itself, you could even return the same iterator instance for all invocations of `iterator()`.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I had not enough coffee yet -- the information for that is with the caller, not the Iterator. So to each caller its own Iterator.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fact that the enum values have assigned to them integer values to cycle through them.